# Logical not() in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Okay were trying to solve a simple Prolog problem, we have a given programm

```
a.
f(X) :- f(X).
```

and a given query

```
not(a).
```

which will obviously return false, question is how can we change the Programm, not the query, to have it return true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write the clause `a:-false`. 
Then when you query not(a). it returns true.